# How use Video.js player via Flash fallback without CDN swf file

Tags: html5-video, video.js, zencoder

IE8 or older automatically uses flash fallback player but the player is hosted in CDN.

I want to use hosted `video-js.swf` file in my server instead of CDN contents.
Because CDN swf file is not secured.

The Video.js version is 3.2, that is currently you can download from http://videojs.com/.

I tried [this code](http://help.videojs.com/discussions/suggestions/184-using-protocol-relative-urls-to-switch-between-http-and-https) but it does not work.

Can someone help me with the solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the link, I was able to find a swf file listed in one of the links:

http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.swf